# Reindexing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, serialization

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/borayeris/jcqwj/) is my example.

Can you tell me how can I make the array have consecutive keys? I want to reindex my array.

Currently I have:

```js
var testArray = new Array();
testArray[3]="qwerty";
testArray[7]="asdfgh";
testArray[13]="zxcvbn";

console.log(testArray);
```

But I'd like to get the values at indices 0, 1 and 2 (and so on):

```
["qwerty", "asdfgh", "zxcvbn"]
```

Comment: He probably wants to reindex the array, judging from his fiddle.

Comment: @warren; in my example array keys are 3, 7, 13. When I serialized them it became ",,,qwerty,,,,asdfgh,,,,,,zxcvbn". What I want is "qwerty,asdfgh,zxcvbn".

Comment: you're just missing what to join the array with.  Having nothing in your `.join()` will result in the commas.  you need at least single quotes (`.join('')`), but that will put the results right next to each other

Comment: @Alin. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind using javascript 1.6: (note: this code uses the jQUery library)

```
var testArray = new Array();
testArray[3]="qwerty";
testArray[7]="asdfgh";
testArray[13]="zxcvbn";
var testString = testArray.filter(function (item) { return item != undefined }).join();

$(function(){
    $('#write').text(testString);
});
```

filter prototype:

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      {
        var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 40):

`Array.prototype.filter()` is not executed on deleted or previously undefined items. So you can simply do:

```
testArray.filter(function(val){return val});
```

..in order to re-index your array.

Or ES6:

```
testArray.filter(val => val)
```

Comment: Note that it will return a new array without affecting `testArray`. You might want to redefine it: `testArray = testArray.filter(val => val);`

Comment: @pmrotule if you want to keep it around, yes. Following the example in the question, shortest would be `var testString = testArray.filter(val => val).join();`

Comment: This answer is wrong. Filter expects the callback to return `true` or `false`. If your array has falsy values such as `null` or `false` they will be removed too. You should always return `true` such as `testArray = testArray.filter(val => true)`

Answer (score 6):

You could filter the array by using a callback which returns `true` or other [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, because [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) omits sparse elements.

If `Boolean` is taken, the result filters not only sparse items, but items which have a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value. To prevent this, take a callback which returns `true` for every element.

```
array.filter(_ => true);
```

```js
var array = [];

array[10] = 0;
array[20] = 0;
array[30] = 0;

console.log(array.filter(_ => true).join('|'))
```

Answer (score 5):

Super simple function:

```
function reindex_array_keys(array, start){
    var temp = [];
    start = typeof start == 'undefined' ? 0 : start;
    start = typeof start != 'number' ? 0 : start;
    for(var i in array){
        temp[start++] = array[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
testArray = reindex_array_keys(testArray);
```

Note: this will blow away any custom keys.  the result will always be numerically indexed. you could add in checks for if it's an array or not but i tend to just not use functions i build other than they are intended to be used.  you can also start the index higher if you like:

```
testArray = reindex_array_keys(testArray, 3);
```

which will produce 3 'undefined' items at the beginning of the array.  you can then add to it later but i think it would be better to do `testArray.unshift('newValue')` first then reindex personally.

have fun

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined

Answer (score 3):

To reindex an array, use `Object.values`:

```js
var sparseArray = new Array();
sparseArray[3] = "qwerty";
sparseArray[7] = "asdfgh";
sparseArray[13] = "zxcvbn";

let result = Object.values(sparseArray);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: How come this isn't the accepted answer, or at least upvoted?

Answer (score 2):

```
var testArray = new Array();
testArray[3] = "qwerty";
testArray[7] = "asdfgh";
testArray[13] = "zxcvbn";


var isEmpty = function(x) {
   // returns true if x is null and false if it is not.
    if(x!=null){ 
        return true;
    }else{ 
        return false
    } 
}
var newArray=testArray.filter(isEmpty);

var testString2 = newArray.join();

$('#write').text(testString2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
testArray = testArray.filter(Boolean)
```

This should re-index your array.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is simpler to solve the problem:

```
var j=0;
var tmpTab=[];
    
for(var i in origTab) {
 tmpTab[j]=origTab[i];
 ++j;
}
origTab=tmpTab;
delete tmpTab;
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean without the commas? if so just do this `var testString = testArray.join("");` or you can add any char you want between.

Comment: What I need is re-indexing the array. Not this.

Comment: you could always just join the Array and then resplit it with a certain delimiter. Maybe its not that pro but its 2 lines of code.

Comment: joining and re-splitting will not work if array elements are objects, for example

Answer (score -1):

**Try** This

```
var testArray=testArray.join(" ");
```

Comment: What I need is re-indexing the array. Not this.