# Reindex javascript array / object after removing a key

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example:

```
var Cars = {
    1: { "Make": "Honda",
         "Model": "Accord",
         "Color": "Red"
    },
    2: { "Make": "Honda",
         "Model": "Civic",
         "Color": "Silver"
    },
    3: { "Make": "Honda",
         "Model": "Jazz",
         "Color": "Yellow"
    }
```

If I do a `delete.Cars[2];` I will be left with Cars[1] and Cars[3].

I need a way (JS or jQuery) so that when I delete a key, the object reindexes. So, in the example above, I'm left with Cars[1] and Cars[2] (which was Cars[3]).

Comment: Is there a reason you arent using an actual array?

Comment: If you use an array, this question has your answer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Comment: Because you can't have multiple dimensions, I've just checked.

Comment: But you haven't got multiple dimensions :D

Comment: You can have an array of arrays, or an array of objects. (So wherever you checked didn't give all the information.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/vfaZt/ Doesn't work if array.

Comment: That fiddle isn't an array, it's invalid syntax. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/vfaZt/1/ and then read up on the Array [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

Comment: I gathered that... by putting in a jsfiddle, I'm asking for a resolution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because you dont need the keys for the array.

```
var Cars = [
    {
        "Make": "Honda",
        "Model": "Accord",
        "Color": "Red"
    },{
        "Make": "Honda",
        "Model": "Civic",
        "Color": "Silver"
    },{
        "Make": "Honda",
        "Model": "Jazz",
        "Color": "Yellow"
    }
];

alert(Cars[1]['Make']); // Honda
```

Comment: But if I have array like this 
 [
    {key:"label", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
    {key:"notes", sortable:true,resizeable:true},......
 After shift it starts at second param. With index = 1

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at this:

Array:
[Javascript - Reindexing an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759745/javascript-reindexing-an-array)

Object:
[Algorithm to re-index an array of objects after insertion or drag 'n' drop order change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237387/algorithm-to-re-index-an-array-of-objects-after-insertion-or-drag-n-drop-order)

It should do the trick :)

Referencing other developers in this thread, and myself, it will be better to use an **Array**.

Comment: Not. Stop using them and use Array instead. (Well, in fact, it can help, if you do `Array.prototype.splice.call(theStrangeObject, 2, 1)` instead of `delete theStrangeObject[2]`... but no, it does not help, you have no `length` there. Use Array).